# VirtualBox でホストからゲストにネットワークがつながらない

Tags: network, virtualbox

ホストOS  Windows 7 上の
VirtualBox で ubuntu を入れて使用しています

ubuntu 内で 3000 ポートに rails を起動してホストから接続テストを行いたいのですが
ホスト上のブラウザで http://10.0.2.15:3000 にアクセスしても一切反応がなく
しばらくして「接続がタイムアウトしました」が表示されます

Rails がうまくいってないのかと思って
`nc -l 3000`でもやってみましたがかわりません

ubuntu のファイアウォールを確認したところ

```
sudo ufw status
状態: 非アクティブ
```

でした

ゲスト内でネットにはつながってるので NAT 自体は機能しているようです

そこで２点確認なのですが

VirtualBox 窓の右下のネットワークのところに

```
アダプター1(NAT)
IP: 10.0.2.15
ケーブル接続
```

とでてるのでこれがホストから見たゲストのIPでいいのでしょうか？

Windows 側のファイアウォールのことがよく分かってないのですが
ホスト側でも何か設定が必要だったりするのでしょうか？

Comment: NATではなくブリッジだとどうですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://qiita.com/daijinload/items/85f6e84926f41812ed70

こちらを参考にしてポートフォワーディングで IP 空欄にして 3000 番同士を入れると動きました
127.0.0.1 までいれるとなぜか動かなくてよくわかりませんでした

IP 空欄で設定したときに Windows 側でファイアウォールの許可画面がでたのでそのせいかもしれません…